# More specific feedback to OP upon voting to close

Tags: discussion, closing

Although I have been with the wider StackExchange community for a number of years, I still consider myself inexperienced when writing posts on math.SE. Today, for the first time, a [question I posted](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3521675/weighted-average-of-samples-of-a-random-variable) was closed. The reason I received was generic: "Add details and clarify the problem you’re solving". I always strive to post clear and detailed questions, and I am always interested in improving my writing.

However, having reviewed the [Help Center article](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions), it is still not clear to me which aspects are in need of improvement the most. Notation? Rigor? References?

And I don't believe I am, or will be, the first to face this issue. Is it possible to have a process where close voters leave feedback for the OP, if such feedback has not been mentioned by a previous voter? I think this will be very helpful to the OP, and the community in general, in raising the quality of posts.

Comment: Close voters have the option of leaving feedback. Many choose not to. The issues have been discussed here before. Please do a search for earlier discussions of your concerns.

Comment: I've now left you a comment, though I wasn't one who voted to close.  Indeed, while there probably isn't much of an answer that can be given, the Question itself is okay by my standards.  Perhaps there is a chatroom where newish contributors can ask for feedback on Questions that get quickly closed without feedback.  However a certain reputation threshold has to be achieved in order to post in chatrooms, so this doesn't completely address the issue.

Comment: One person suggested their might not be more more people can say, so my guess would be give an example of or help towards an answer you would accept. Also uou typoed expectation but that comes with the mathematics.

Comment: @GerryMyerson It has been discussed before, but the new close reason "lacking details and clarity" instead of "lacking context" has changed the situation, imo. Often close voters use it for question that do lack context by this site's standards, but not details or clarity. That makes it quite hard for new users do get what is expected from them.

Comment: Recently the "lacking context" (which includes, but is not limited to, questions that look like homework where the OP does not show their own attempts at the question) close reason has been merged with "needs details or clarity". It's possible that some users judged that your question was lacking context as you did not provide your own attempts or motivation regarding where the problem came from. I would disagree with this judgement, but I think it's a plausible reason why some may have voted to close.

Comment: And, @MaoWao, "lacking context" is, essentially, lacking sufficient details and clarity.  E.g., If users are looking for more context in a question, that's essentially saying, they are looking for more details from the asker, and more clarity so the question can be answered.  But I agree that both the "lacking context" reason, and the "lacking detains and clarity", without further explication in comments, isn't a clear-cut recipe for improving a post.  I think the hope is that the asker steps away to view the post as others see it, so they can try and be as helpul as possible to answerers.

Comment: Thanks to all who took the time to read my Meta question - I have since then received quite a few helpful ideas for improving my original question. In particular, adding context and motivation one thing I have not considered before. I know the question posts are many, and it take time to leave feedback, but I think this can go a long way to help newer users.